# generating random coordinates in a country

Tags: r, geospatial

I'm trying to randomly generate a list of coordinates that fall within a country boundary in R. Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The sf package provides this functionality.

```
st_sample("sf-object", size = 2000, type = "random", crs = st_crs(4326))
```

Which can be used like this:

```
library(sf)
library(spData)

Germany <- world[world$name_long == "Germany", 0]
rpoints <- st_sample(Germany, size = 100, type = "random", crs = st_crs(4326))
```

As sf-object you can pass anything, a LINESTRING, a POLYGON etc. The points will then be sampled on this LINESTRING or in this POLYGON. So you just need a Polygon of the country you want to sample in. The `world` dataset from the `spData`-package has all countries as sf-object.

Alternatively there is the `spsample()`-function from the `sp`-package, which takes a sp-object.

Comment: so would I download a polygon of the country and then sample within it?

Comment: No need to download it. I have made an update

Comment: amazing, thanks so much!